# Is range bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

If a function f is continuous on an open interval (let's say (a,b)), does that mean that the range of the function (i.e. f((a,b))) bounded?

I know this is true if the function is closed but not sure if the interval is open.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Take $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ on $(0,1)$